# cordova open created local file on iPad

Tags: javascript, cordova

I create a local pdf file using jsPdf, then I wan't to open it in it's proper native app (adobe reader for example) giving the user th posibility to print the file.

For Android I used this plugin https://github.com/jwark/FileOpener/tree/cordova-3.0 and it works great!

But for iOS (just iPad no iPhone support needed) I can't find any solution, just this one http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/08/15/open-with-in-ios-phonegap-apps/ but people on the comments say that it doesn't support cordova 3 and it doesn't have the config.xml file...

I also tried to open the pdf file using the inAppBrowser (I don't know if this one will th user the ability to print the file) but the filesystem doesn't return a valid file using both fileEntry.fullpath and fileEntry.toURL()

any solution is appreciated !
Thanks in advance !

Cordova 3.4.0
File system

Comment: Is my question not clear?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i am in a similar situation as you question